# Has anyone developed a front end for ELMAH?

Tags: elmah

The default web interface is fine for exception logging, but I am using it for general logging and need to get some other people to be able to examine the logs. I was just thinking that someone else may have already developed a front end for it.

Answer (score 1):

I recently ran into the [ASP.NET Exception Reporter (based on ELMAH)](http://aspexceptionreporter.codeplex.com/) project on codeplex. They've built a UI for ELMAH that organizes by type of error.

Comment: This is overcomplicated for what I require. This solution requires a whole web service and separate db as well as a windows service to scrape the elmah xml from the original server. I agree, it IS a solution but its over complicated.